# How can I connect a PHP/Codeigniter application to a remote MySQL database via SSH tunnel?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, ssh, mysqli

I am refactoring a spaghetti code PHP application into the Codeigniter framework and the development version of the application is on a different server than the production database. For testing, I would like to establish an ssh tunnel from my EC2 instance where I am hosting the development version to the production database. I have successfully created an ssh connection with the remote server via libssh2 AND with phpseclib (http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). However, after the ssh tunnel has been established, I am not able to connect to the database with the codeigniter mysqli db driver.

With every attempt to connect to the database, I get the following error:

**Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: core/MY_Controller.php
Line Number: 6**

The MY_Controller code is:

```
1  <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
2
3  class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
4 
5  public function __construct() {
6       parent::__construct();
7       $this->auth = new stdClass;
8       $this->load->library('flexi_auth');
9       if (!$this->flexi_auth->is_logged_in()) {
10          header('Location: /login');
11      }
12  }
```

I have modified the mysqli driver to include the tunnel object as a parameter in the mysqli real_connect function as follows, to no avail. Does anyone know how I can make this work?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Mike

Comment: Er - are you SURE you want to connect a development system to a production database? You'd be better replicating the production database on your development system.

Comment: The production database is 1TB+ and it would be an enormous effort to replicate the production database on the development server. I appreciate your caution, but I am curious about the possibility aside from that issue - if I am connecting to a remote development database via ssh, or I want the production app to remotely tunnel into a production database, is there a way to make it work? Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I think my first attempt would be to create an `ssh` tunnel like this:

```
my_dev_ec2# ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 myuser@my_production_ec2
```

And then config the mysqli db to connect to `localhost` as if it was in the production instance.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would really prefer the app establish the connection programmatically, which I have been able to do with both libssh2 and phpseclib, separately. However, the Codeigniter mysqli database driver, even when I have modified it to accept the ssh_tunnel object as an argument, does not make the connection.